# How to change mouse cursor using powershell script on windows 11 without restarting?

Tags: powershell, script, mouse, windows-11, themes

I am having some hard time trying to change mouse cursor using PowerShell script on windows 11.
[I have this application called WDD scripts](https://github.com/t1m0thyj/WDD-scripts#readme) which have the power of PowerShell scripts depending on the time of the day/ dark or light system OS theme.

I am having hard time writing a script to change mouse cursor using powershell script.
this is what I done so far (checked if theme uses light/dark theme).
Now the missing part is how to change the mouse cursor.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$daySegment2,  # 0 = Day, 1 = Night
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$daySegment4,  # -1 = N/A, 0 = Sunrise, 1 = Day, 2 = Sunset, 3 = Night
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$nightMode,   # True if night mode is enabled
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$imagePath # Path to current wallpaper image
)

$NightValue = If ($nightMode) {1} Else {$daySegment2}
if ( $NightValue -eq 0)
{
    //change mouse cursor to light
}
else
{
    //change mouse cursor to dark
}
```

I have seen many application that solves this issue like [Auto Dark Mode](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/auto-dark-mode/XP8JK4HZBVF435), But no one is sharing how they done it.
I am trying to change mouse scheme as shown in the image below:
[image: Light mode]

and Windows Black scheme when it is dark mode.
I tried changing every registry to dark mode in here, the settings is updated but not the cursor itself.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors
[image: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel]

Comment: Try restarting explorer

Comment: Can I do this without restarting my explorer.exe? When I change mouse scheme using window settings, I don't need to restart the explorer.

Comment: No.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was deeply studied in the article
[Use PowerShell to Change the Mouse Pointer Scheme](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-scheme/).

The author concluded that it's not enough to change the registry settings,
but one also needs to use a Windows API call to `SystemParametersInfo`
in order to put them into effect.
This requires escaping into another programming language, in this case C#.

Here is the solution from the post:

> First, we’ll grab the C# Signature from MSDN and store it as a
> here-string within my script:
>
> ```
> $CSharpSig = @’
> [DllImport(“user32.dll”, EntryPoint = “SystemParametersInfo”)]
> public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
>              uint uiAction,
>              uint uiParam,
>              uint pvParam,
>              uint fWinIni);
> ‘@
> ```
>
> Next, we’ll use Add-Type with the C# signature as the value for the
> `MemberDefinition` parameter, and give it a name and a namespace.
>
> ```
> $CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
> ```
>
> Finally, we’ll call the method `SystemParametersInfo` with the arguments
> dictated by the MSDN reference page:
>
> ```
> $CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
> ```
>
> If all is well, when this is executed, the mouse pointer scheme will
> be updated and Windows PowerShell will return True.

Comment: I receive this error:
Exception calling "SystemParametersInfo" with "4" argument(s): "Unable to load DLL 'user32.dll”, EntryPoint = “SystemParametersInfo': The specified module could not be 
found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
At C:\Users\yazan\AppData\Local\WinDynamicDesktop\scripts\ChangeMouseScheme.ps1:37 char:1
+ $CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DllNotFoundException

Comment: I think the above method is too convoluted and `SystemParametersInfo` can be directly called from PowerShell as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180893/how-to-change-wall-paper-by-using-powershell). If it works for you, I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: Thanks this worked After some digging. I solved all the issues.

Answer (score -1):

As DavidPostill has eluded to, registry keys are re-loaded when you start `explorer.exe`. You can force this process by:

1. Bring up Task Manager
2. Find Windows Explorer
3. Right-click it, and choose `End Task`

[image]

4. Whilst still in Task Manager, click `File` > `Run New Task`
5. Type `explorer.exe` into the prompt

[image]

6. Click OK, and Windows Explorer will re-launch with your new settings applied.

Comment: Can I do this without restarting my explorer.exe?
When I change mouse scheme using window settings, I don't need to restart the explorer.

Comment: No, registry keys won't be re-read until explorer.exe loads up.