# Windows does not respect theme switch done by registry

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry, windows-11, themes

I am using Windows 11 22H2 build 22621.1265.
I use these scripts to change the system/application theme accordingly:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force;
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force
```

Windows do not respect the theme switch when the scripts are run, as shown in these images below:[image: Windows Does not respect theme switch #1]
[image: Windows Does not respect theme switch #2]
[image: Windows Does not respect theme switch #3]
[image: Windows Does not respect theme switch #4]

I think the font color and other system parameters must be reloaded after changing the registry.
[In my mouse script](https://superuser.com/questions/1769195/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-using-powershell-script-on-windows-11-without-restart): https://superuser.com/questions/1769195/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-using-powershell-script-on-windows-11-without-restart

After I changed the registry, I called system parameters to reload the new mouse value that are in the registry.

```
$CSharpSig = @’
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
             uint uiAction,
             uint uiParam,
             uint pvParam,
             uint fWinIni);
‘@
$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
```

I just need to know which API needs to be called to reload these values, And how can I call it using powershell?
I want the changes to be reloaded without restarting the explorer.
Please check what I did in my mouse script.

Comment: You need to restart explorer in order for it to pick up the registry changes

Comment: I want the changes to be called without restarting the explorer.
Please check what I did in my mouse script.

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Comment: Relevant: [windows - Win32: Reloading theme after theme-related registry changes? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75429695/win32-reloading-theme-after-theme-related-registry-changes)

Comment: Can I save the current folder position/folder path and retrieve/open it after the explorer restart?
for example if:
1) "Drive/Work/Receipts" folder path were opened in file explorer.
2) save this folder path to txt file.
3) restart explorer.exe.
4) open the folder path in the txt file.

Comment: I have no idea...